# DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler in WPF catching exception is visual studio but not writing the logs in client machine

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

We have a WPF windows desktop client application in which I have written logic for handling the Global unhandled exception and thread level exception and all.

But when I have tried with Null reference exception and its writing the logs correctly in my development machine using visual studio, But When we release this application and users installing in their machines because of some unhandled exception application is getting crashed and not writing the logs in users machines.

What I am missing here I dont know.

```
 <Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
         Startup="Application_Startup"
         DispatcherUnhandledException ="AppDispatcherUnhandledException">
<Application.Resources>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Global exception handling
        try
        {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
  UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new 
   ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new 

DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDispatcherUnhandledException);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("AppStart"));
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exc.StackTrace));
        }
    }

  void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, 
 UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception exception = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;

    Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("DomainLevel"));

  Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exception.Message));

    Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exception.StackTrace));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fatal Non-UI Error",
                    "Fatal Non-UI Error. Could not write the error to the 
  event log. Reason: "
                    + exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("Domain 
  Finally"));

  Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exc.StackTrace));
            }
        }
    }

  void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Log the exception, display it, etc
        try
        {
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("AppThread 
 Try"));

 Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(e.Exception.Message));

 Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(e.Exception.StackTrace));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("AppThread 
Catch"));
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exc.Message));
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal Non-UI Error",
                    "Fatal Non-UI Error. Could not write the error to the 
event log. Reason: "
                    + exc.Message);
        }
    }

    void AppDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, 
DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        {
           // #if DEBUG   // In debug mode do not custom-handle the 
  exception, let Visual Studio handle it
            try
            {
                e.Handled = false;

               // #else

                ShowUnhandledException(e);

             //    #endif
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

    Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exc.StackTrace));
                MessageBox.Show("Fatal Non-UI Error",
                        "Fatal Non-UI Error. Could not write the error to 
   the event log. Reason: "
                        + exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    void ShowUnhandledException(DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("Dispatcher 
try"));

Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(e.Exception.Message));

Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(e.Exception.StackTrace));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal("Dispatcher 
 Catch"));
            Logger.LogEntry(LogModel.Create(this).Fatal(exc.Message));
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal Non-UI Error",
                    "Fatal Non-UI Error. Could not write the error to the 
event log. Reason: "
                    + exc.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void LogEntry(ILogEntry entry)
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(entry.SourceComponentName);

        var message = string.Format("{0}::L{1} {2} - {3}", entry.SourceMemberName, entry.SourceLineNumber, entry.Text, entry.SourceFilePath.Split('\        \').LastOrDefault());

        else if (entry.Level == LogLevelState.Error)
        {
            log.Error(message);
        }
        else if (entry.Level == LogLevelState.Fatal)
        {
            log.Fatal(message);
        }
       #if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine(message);
#endif
    }

        public static LogModel Create<T>(T source = default(T), [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null, [CallerFilePath] string      callerFilePath = null, [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = 0)
    {
        return new LogModel
        {
            SourceComponentName = typeof(T).Name,
            SourceMemberName = callerMemberName,
            SourceFilePath = callerFilePath,
            SourceLineNumber = callerLineNumber
        };
    }

public LogModel Fatal(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Level = LogLevelState.Fatal;
        Text = string.Format(format, args);

        return this;
    }
```

Edit:

In EventViewer

First Event:

Error   5/15/2018 11:32:52 PM   .NET Runtime    1026    None

Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000008, exception address 00007FFECBB12B10

Second Event:
Error   5/15/2018 11:32:54 PM   Application Error   1000    Application Crashing Events

Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 2.0.0.1769, time stamp: 0x5af68c0a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x493793ea
Exception code: 0xc0000008
Fault offset: 0x0000000000002b10
Faulting process id: 0x15bd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3eb91be5a688c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 7c3cba0e-7438-491e-a9da-7871858212ef
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Where does the Logger write to?

Comment: @CSharper it will be written in a text file in our local computer(users). Its writing other logs except crashing in client logs but locally while debugging visual studio its writing unhandled logs as well in text file.

Comment: DispatcherUnhandledException ="AppDispatcherUnhandledException"> same has    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new 

DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDispatcherUnhandledException);

Answer (score 1):

**Any of the code in your `catch` blocks could potentially fail.** This includes, but is not limited to:

- the calls to the `LogEntry` method of your `Logger` instance
- the calls to the `LogEntryModel.Create` method
- the calls to the `Fatal` method of the LogEntryModel class

If your app is still crashing, and not logging anything, I would suspect the problem lies when calling the code inside the `catch` blocks.

Comment: The thing is everything is works perfectly locally in visual studio but not writing the logs in only client machines means only the crashing logs other than that normal logs are getting written in the log files and working fine.

Comment: Your development machine and the client machine are two different environments. I would suspect that your logging framework is making some assumptions that happen to be true on your machine, but are not true elsewhere. It could be something as simple as the logging folder existing on your machine but not others. Or it could be more complicated than that. Maybe add your logging code to your question?

Comment: I dont think such folder problems are there because its writing all the logs except that unhandling and even in my machine that too works fine. I have added my full code please check.